# Select the second button in an angular material modal

Tags: html, angular, angular-material-5

I have a simple modal in angular material. I want to focus the yes button when it opens / is loaded. I did achieve this by setting `tabindex='-1'` on the no button and `autoFocus: true` in the provider. However this causes an UX issue where you cannot focus the no button with your keyboard. How can I focus the second button while keeping it accessible by keyboard. I also tried using `tabindex`, which did not appear to affect the selection. I am looking for an elegant solution ( so preferably without writing some typescript to solve it )

**dialog.component.html**

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Cookie request</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>Should we use a cookie to automatically log you in next time?</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]='false' tabindex='-1'>No</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true"  tabindex='1'>Yes</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

**excerpt from app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...stuff],
  imports: [...stuff],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DIALOG_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {hasBackdrop: true, disableClose: true, autoFocus: true }}
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DialogComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

The official docs: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api

Optional: how do I enforce focus to stay inside my modal until it's closed?

Comment: On a sidenote I used `cdkTrapFocus` in a `div` surrounding the provided snipped to keep focus inside my modal: https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/api#CdkTrapFocus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [Stackblitz of material dialog](https://pejaqygmgjx.angular.stackblitz.io), you can see they are using `cdkFocusInitial` to `focus the OK button`.

[**Edit :** maybe not accurate, but still interesting !] To navigate to the other focusable element (If needed), tabindex does not seems towork properly but I think your answer is here : [Angular A11y](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview)

**[Edit 2] :** Since some people can't access stackblitz properly, here the sample of the dialog html code:

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite Animal</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">No Thanks</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't open the StackBlitz link. Can you provide the relevant code in your answer? That said `cdkFocusInitial` seems to work ;).

Comment: @RMo The `cdkFocusInitial` is all you need to set the focus and keep the navigation with your keyboard. Don't forget to remove your other tabindex. Is there something else you need that i didn't cover ? (I'll edit to provide example)